# How to add my Rails App to Heroku?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have made a Rails 3 App with Aptana Studio. This application is already in Github. I tried engine yard to deploy my app. You should specify to engine yard which is the address from your code in github and automatically he make a copy in your server instance.

Here is my problem.... The client asked to deploy the app with heroku. I would like to use the code which i have in github and deploy it in heroku.

Which is the fastest way to make an heroku app using my code in github? Heroku can take the code from github? Which is the process to follow?

I read the quick start from heroku with rails but they suggest to make a new app and copy file by file in the new heroku app.

Thanks all!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you asked for the quikest shortest way, I think that is:

1. Install the heroku gem (gem install heroku)
2. Create a new app on heroku.  `heroku create`
   -# Note the output and the app name, e.g. "`sharp-rock-2853`"
3. In your existing local app, `$ heroku git:remote -a sharp-rock-2853`
   -# replace sharp-rock-2853 with your heroku app name from step 1
4. `git push heroku master`

Comment: Thanks Michael, with this steps I could solve it. Just before i solve a problem with the rss pub key.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku documentation cover this topic in quite length:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

Re: MySQL, while you don't have MySQL in Heroku, as long you don't use MySQL specific features (most likely if you used ActiveRecord you didn't) then you shouldn't have any problem deploying your application to heroku.

As for deployment, Heroku deployment works like pushing changes to GitHub, to deploy your application you `push` your codebase to it.

```
git push heroku master
```

Will deploy your master branch to Heroku.

Of course, for this to work you need:

- An account on Heroku
- Have installed Heroku gem (`gem install heroku`)
- Have created an application on heroku (see Heroku documentation)

From the Heroku devcenter link, you can skip the create an app step and focus on the other details, like database adapter, groups and such.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial from Heroku itself: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git